# How to extract information out of a cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to extract information out of a cell in Google Sheets.  The data for a football match all comes through in one cell and it's my job to separate some of that information into separate cells.  The image attached is an example of the data.  I need to sort it into 3 columns.  Home Team (yellow), Away Team (green) and Market (blue).  The data is always in the same format.  Home team after the kickoff time and before " v".  Away Team after " v" and before "".  Market between 2 "".  What is the best way to do this?

I've tried using LEFT, MID and RIGHT but it's not perfect and I know there is a more advanced way to do it that's just a bit about my skill level.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjmtr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula-

```
=CHOOSECOLS(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2," v ","|"),"\","|")," ","|",1),"|"),2,3,4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=index(ifna(regexextract(A2:A,"\d (.*) v (.*?)\\(.*?)\\")))
```

[image]